# Tomcat startup fails with not a valid identifier

Tags: tomcat, startup, tomcat6

I have tomcat 6.0.18 running on one server without a problem. With the exact same settings it fails to launch on my colleague's machine. He's even running from the same folder as me (I've stopped my copy while he tries to make it work)

All we get when we fire off tomcat using bin/startup.sh is this:

CATALINA_OPTS=-server -Xms768m -XX:+UseParallelGC -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=128m -Djava.awt.headless=true: **is not an identifier**

I had that definition in setenv.sh and moved it into startup.sh - same problem.

Any suggestions? My brief look on google seem to indicate multiple IP address issues, but my server has two ethernet cards, and two IP addresses.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a shell script and not a Tomcat problem. The correct way to do it is:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="....."
```

Your colleague is probably using a different shell than you.

Comment: Ah! Hadn't thought of shells being different. I will ask him what he's running. It is quoted - but with single quotes (which works fine on my server using bash) and is being exported. For some reason the error message doesn't indicate that.

Comment: It makes sense if he is using a Bourne Shell. Then you would need to do the export in two steps: CATALINA_OPTS="  " and then export CATALINA_OPTS

Comment: That was it! He was using a different shell. Since this is a one off, I have edited catalina.sh to define the OPTS in there. No need for export, and now we are running.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not much to go on there. Shouldn't the value of CATALINA_OPTS be quoted?:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-server -Xms768m -XX:+UseParallelGC -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=128m -Djava.awt.headless=true"
```

Other than that

- Does it start up with out any options
  and/or any applications installed?
- Is it even getting as fair as launching
  the actual java process?

Comment: It is quoted in the script, don't know why the error message is less than helpful in that regard. 
I will try without any options - he had to dash off to a meeting before we tried some ideas :(
don't think the java process is launching, he said it just comes back to the shell prompt
He's in a secure room and I'm not. Hence the lack of info, sorry!